# DataTables POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I use DataTables but when I want to send data with an Ajax POST type I get error message:

> Invalid JSON primitive: draw.

But when I use GET it's OK a little error:

> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the
>   query string is too long.

How can I send data with POST, please?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#table').dataTable({
                proccessing: true,
                pagingType: "full_numbers",
                cache: false,
                serverSide: true, 
                stateSave: true,
                ajax: { 
                    "url": '@Url.Action("PageData", "Home")',
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "dataType": "json"
                },
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `request filtering module` is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long means you need to
Increase the value of the `maxQueryString` in `web.config` file.

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

you can set length as your need and one thing more
check your json it is valid json or not

```
 var yourData=  {'foo':'foovalue', 'bar':'barvalue'}
```

and you can send data like

```
data: JSON.stringify(yourData)
```

Comment: I mentioned it as a little error but what I do not understand, why POST request gives me this error:  Invalid JSON primitive: draw.

Comment: But it is a DataTables where I do not need to stringify my data. I have to set only server side URL.